# CSS3, HTML - how to arrange blocks like this

Tags: html, css

```
<div class="outer-wrapper">
    <div class="inner-wrapper">
        <div class="item">1</div>
        <!--...-->
        <div class="item">12</div>
    </div>
</div>

.outer-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    min-width: 900px;
    max-width: 900px;
    min-height: 600px;
    max-height: 600px;
}
.inner-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 20000em;
}
.item {
    min-height: 350px;
    max-height: 350px;
    min-width: 350px;
    max-width: 350px;
    background: cornflowerblue;
    font-size: 40px;
    float: left;
}
```

I have attached image:

[image]

How to arrange items in such way without wrapping groups (each six items) in additional container? Is it possible?

Comment: Why are doing an easy thing so hard? You can simply create two grids

Comment: Use [nth-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) or [nth-of-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a combination of column-count and float:

http://jsfiddle.net/JqRv3/1/

```
ol {
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-count:    2;
    column-count:         2;
}
li {
    list-style: decimal inside;
    width: 33.3333%;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: Also, note that this is not supported in IE9 and earlier.